# What are some common counterintuitive classical physics phenomena that you can think of?

Tags: classical-mechanics, everyday-life, big-list

Some ordinary and everyday physics phenomena are counterintuitive when first encountered. Examples:

1. demo of moment of inertia of cylinders rolling down an inclined plane by prof Walter Lewin: https://youtu.be/cB8GNQuyMPc
2. better aerodynamic design for spaceship re-entering the atmosphere : https://youtu.be/v1_WqVguRJg (start watching from 43:23)
3. leaning tower of Pisa experiment by Galileo Galilei to prove that heavier and lighter objects take same time to fall from a given height

Comment: Kapitza's pendulum is pretty strange (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapitza%27s_pendulum), a double-hinged pendulum which can be in dynamic  equilibrium pointing up.

Comment: Thanks Cryo...I wasn't aware of something like kapitza's pendulum. Reminded of watt governor